Are aminobenzene and phenylamine accepted IUPAC names?
I always find myself confused when deciding what to name compounds that are derivatives of benzene. As I understand there's a preferred name (that's usually trivial) and a systematic name(s) that are all considered valid IUPAC names(?).
If we take the example of aniline, I've come across the following names: phenylamine, aminobenzene, benzenamine, and aniline itself. Of these, the most obvious is aniline which is the PIN.
From what little I know of the IUPAC rules, I used the following process of elimination to deduce that of the remaining three, only benzenamine conforms to the IUPAC rules:

For mono-substituted benzene derivatives, substituents that cannot act as principal functional groups are always prefixed (ex: halo, nitro, alkyl, alkoxy) while the ones that can are suffixed (ex: -COOH). This lead me to eliminate aminobenzene as amines can act as PFGs and should therefore be suffixed (as benzenamine).
Benzene is only treated as a substituent (phenyl) if a side-chain containing another principal functional group is attached to it. In this case, there aren't any side-chains and therefore phenylamine is wrong as well.

However, my teacher insists that both phenylamine and aminobenzene are valid IUPAC names for aniline, while my textbook says that aminobenzene is a valid name but doesn't mention anything about phenylamine. Is my rationale correct or is there something that I'm missing?

Wikipedia identifies both phenylamine and aminobenzene as acceptable names, along with benzamine and the systematic name benzenamine. But the preferred IUPAC name is simply... aniline.
